# Exclude .js files from build React.js

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-scripts

I was wondering if there was a way to exclude a .js file from

`npm run build`

I have tried adding

```json
"build": "react-scripts build && rm -rf build/config-local.js",
```

into `package.json` but it tells me:

> `rm is not recognized as a function`

is there a simple solution to this issue

Thank you

Comment: `rm` is not recognized because you are probably using a Windows system. Try `del`.

Comment: Also, this is really an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I am not at the liberty of selecting a system, I have to use windows for this specific app.

Comment: i am aware this is an XY problem ish I am trying to find the cleanest way to exclude a file from build.

Comment: I didn't say you had to switch the OS, just try the `del` command: `&& del build\\config-local.js` -- Note the escaped backslash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot exclude a `.js` file which is installed via your `react-scripts build` command without modifying [react-scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts) source code. So, I think your attempted solution of subsequently deleting the file is the simplest approach.

**Explanation:**

So why is it not working?

> `rm is not recognized as a function`

- The [`rm`](https://ss64.com/bash/rm.html) command is for removing files/folders via bash.
- The equivalent command for Windows (E.g. via `cmd.exe`) is [`DEL`](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html).

So my guess is you're getting this error because you're running it on Windows.

**Solution:**

For a cross platform solution to removing file/folders(s) you can utilize [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf).

1. Firstly `cd` to your project directory and install `rimraf` by running the following command:

   ```
   npm install rimraf --save-dev
   ```
2. Then change your `build` script to the following in your `package.json`:

   ```json
   "build": "react-scripts build && rimraf build/config-local.js",
   ```

   **Note**: the original `rm -rf` part has been replaced with `rimraf`

Comment: I got a couple dependancy issues with rimraf but it worked, thank you very much for your help, you saved me a lot of research